# Stacked divs equaling one height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking for a solution where I can change the height of a div based on the total height of three divs (One of which is variable based on content).
[image: Graphic of Div Layout]

The Green Div will change height based on content.  The yellow divs don't.  I would like the height of the blue div to change based on the total height of the three left divs.  I'm trying to get the top and bottom of all the divs to match up.

Jquery is a good option for my site, I'm just not sure how I would set this up.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is what CSS is for. I'll add the tag for you...

Comment: If green has varying height, yellows cannot have.

Comment: If I underestand, what you like is the blue div resize according to the height of the sum of theese 3 div from the left, am I right?

Comment: jcvegan, yes, exactly.

Comment: I would think that it would need to be jquery or JS becasue the green div height is based on dynamic content loaded from a database.

Comment: jQuery... nope... why? maybe we should learn about position relative and position absolute instead.

Comment: I just assumed. But I guess I know what that makes me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play resizing the textarea:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/dxpB2/

```
div.box {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 110px 0 0;
}

div.fixed {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FFF601;
}

div.variable {
    margin: 10px 0;
    background-color: #00FF0D;
}

div.lateral {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #9699FF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to add jquery you can just add this line to your page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Or you can download the actual file and reference it correctly.

Now you are saying the green div will adjust based on content. After you set the content inside the div you should be setting the blue divs height.

```
$("#blue").height($("#yellow1").height() + $("#green").height() + $("#yellow2").height());
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a JS fiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/GgPJq/

Every time you click on the Green Text it doubles.

This gets you to where you need to be

```
jQuery(".blue").css("height", jQuery("#left").outerHeight());
```

Basically every time green expands the line above changes the style to match.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two and a half pure CSS solutions.

First solution requires to wrap all four div's in a container element with `position: relative` set to it.

Then the blue div can be positioned absolutely and forced to inherit the containers/wrappers height (which comes from the total height of the yellow and green div's) like so:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

The width of the blue div can be set explicitly, or with `left`, depending on how responsive the layout needs to be. And the horizontal space taken up by the blue div can be compensated on the wrapper with `padding-right`.

But no-one really wants extra DOM elements to achieve proper layout, do they.

Another option would be to set `position: relative` on the green div and place the blue div as a child of the green div in the DOM. Then position the blue div so:

```
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: -x; /* Whatever is the height of the top yellow div and margin between*/
bottom: x; /* Whatever is the height of the bottom yellow div and margin between */
width: x; /* Set explicitly for example */
```

This is possible due to the fact that yellow div's are of fixed height.

And extending it further, the entire blue div can be accomplished by the `::after` pseudo element on the green div (same CSS applies as for the second solution), but it's suitability depends on what the contents of the blue div need to be.

Comment: Ahh, @coma beat me to it for the first solution.

Comment: I'm glad to see that I'm not the only one using only CSS here, thank you.